# sbt-assembly: skip specific test

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I would like to configure `sbt-assembly` to skip a specific test class.

Is there any way to do this? If it helps, I tagged the test using ScalaTest `@Network` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Additional test configurations with shared sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources). This allows you to come up with alternative "test" task in `FunTest` configuration while reusing your test source.

After you have `fun:test` working with whatever filter you define using `testOptions in FunTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(itFilter))`, you can then rewire

```
test in assembly := test in FunTest
```

Answer (score 1):

Eugene is right (obviously) but that wasn't quite enough information for me to get it to work - I have a `build.scala` file. I am defining `baseSettings` like this:

```
     val baseSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ 
                        buildSettings ++  
                        Seq(sbt.Keys.test in assembly := {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your tests with `ignore`, then sbt/ScalaTest won't run them. See ScalaTest docs on [Tagging tests](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests).

Just for completeness, if you want to skip all tests in assembly task or run only particular ones you can customize it with `test in assembly := { ... }`

Comment: my question is precisely about skipping specific tests in `sbt-assembly`: let my test name be `VerySlowTest`, could you provide an example on how to configure `sbt-assembly` to ignore this test?

Comment: In the solution, that I suggested you don't need to do anything with sbt-assembly, instead you can add the `ignore` tag to the test, in the definition of the test (see the link I gave to the ScalaTest docs). I can't just show you the code, because it depends on the way you define your test.
Anyway, I think @eugene-yokota already suggested a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @eugene-yokata reply, I found how to use the flag from ScalaTest:

```scala
lazy val UnitTest = config("unit") extend (Test)

lazy val companyApp = (project in file("applications/"))
      .assembly("com.company.app", "app.jar")
      .configs(UnitTest)
      .settings(
        inConfig(UnitTest)(Defaults.testTasks),
        UnitTest / testOptions ++= Seq(
          Tests.Argument(
            TestFrameworks.ScalaTest,
            "-l",
            "com.company.tag.HttpIntegrationTest"
          ),
          Tests.Argument(
            TestFrameworks.ScalaTest,
            "-l",
            "com.company.tag.EsIntegrationTest"
          )
        ),
        test in assembly := (UnitTest / test).value
      )
```